# Why is btoa not converting my byte array as expected?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, base64, type-conversion

In my .Net MVC app, I have a DataTable that has an image column.  The image is stored in SQL as varbinary.  The controller passes the "image" to the razor as a byte array, then the Razor renders it in an img tag like so:

```
string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.Image);
string imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
<img src="@imageSrc" height="50" />
```

This works perfectly. But, for several reasons (which are all very boring), we need to redo the table so that it's constructed in JQuery.  Which means, when the image column is built, it needs to convert the image data into a Base64 string.  I've been turned on to the btoa function in jQuery, but it's not converting it to a Base64 string identical to the Razor method above, which causes a broken image in the grid.  My jQuery is as follows:

```
var imgData = btoa(data);
return "<img src=\"data:image/gif;base64," + imgData + "\" />";
```

Note: `item.Image` in the first block and `data` in the second block are being passed the same thing... a 90,514-part array with (seemingly) the same sequence of elements.

I've also tried casting the "data" as a string like `btoa(data.toString())`, but that didn't work.  It looks like `ToBase64String` accepts a byte array while `btoa` accepts a string.  To be honest, I don't even want to use `btoa` because I understand it won't work in even *recent* versions of IE.  So, if anyone has a better suggestion, I'm all ears.  None of the plugins or other methods I've found seem to work.

Essentailly, I'm just trying to figure out why these 2 blocks of code produce different output, and more importantly, how I can change the second block to produce the same output as the first.

For the Record: I would love to post the actual Base64 strings being returned by these code blocks, but whenever I try to paste one of them in the browser, it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I just *love* it when I spend half a day on a problem, post a question on StackOverflow to attempt to find the answer, then just magically stubmble upon the solution 5 minutes later on my own!

Essentially, I figgered out you can do this:

```
var imgString = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, data));
```

However, using this method I was getting an error (viewable in Developer Tools):

> maximum call stack size exceeded error

Upon further research, I found out this error is being caused by a never-ending recursive function somewhere, causing the stack to fill up. I found this modification to the above solution, which ended up doing the trick:

```
var imgString = btoa([].reduce.call(data, function (p, c) { return p + String.fromCharCode(c) }, ''));
```